# How to comment in jspx page

Tags: java, jsp, jspx

How to comment the code in jspx page? I have tried several methods,

```
<!--  -->
<%-- -->
```

but it doesn't not work!

So I have to:

```
<c:if test="${false}">code</c:if>,
```

it is really urgly, Is there any other ways?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

**JSP.1.5.2 Comments in JSP Documents**

Comments in JSP documents use the XML syntax...
The body of the content is ignored completely. [3]

CDATA sections may occur anywhere character data may occur; they are used to escape blocks of text containing characters which would otherwise be recognized as markup. [4]

1. java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref203.html#1004313
2. java.net/jira/browse/JSP_SPEC_PUBLIC-105
3. http://jsp.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf
4. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect

   <![CDATA[<!-- comment -->]]>

Comment: To print a comment in your html output use `<![CDATA[<!-- comment -->]]>` in your jspx documents, you may even add variables `<c:set var="score">10</c:set> <![CDATA[<!-- score: ${score} -->]]>` !

Answer (score 3):

Just use `<!-- comment -->` for comments. JSPX file uses XML syntax so that's the reason XML style comment work here.

Also read article [Creating a JSP Document](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPX3.html) for understanding the difference between JSP standard syntax and XML syntax

Answer (score 0):

You were close with one of your attempts, JSP comments look like below:

```
<%-- some commented out stuff --%>
```

Comment: Thanks,Tendayi. Actually, I have try <%-- some commented --%>,and I always get the exception under tomcat6.0 as below,


org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/login.jspx(12,10) The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried XML IGNORE?

```
<![IGNORE[
  <!-- commented out XML -->
]]>
```

Change IGNORE to INCLUDE when you want it back.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 kinds of comments: JSP comments and HTML comments.

- **JSP** commet: `<%-- comment text --%>`
- **HTML/XML** comment: `<!-- comment -->`

**JSP comments** are **not exported** to HTML and are ignored by the JSP Engine.

**HTML comments** are **exported** to HTML because they are valid HTML tags.